# scala Option and datatypes

Tags: scala, types

i'm getting an error when trying to getOrElse 2 values.  As a stripped down example, all i'm trying to do is:

- take a string value
- check if its a range (eg 50-60).  if it is, take the first value before the '-', else take the whole value
- return the value as an Option[Double] for further processing

```
def deriveResult(inputValue: Option[String]): String = {
    val hyphenIndex = inputValue.get.indexOf("-")
    // parse the low range
    val rangedValue: Option[java.lang.Double] = if (hyphenIndex != -1) {
        val lowRangeStringUntruncated = inputValue.get.substring (0, hyphenIndex)
        val lowRangeString = lowRangeStringUntruncated.substring (0, scala.math.min (lowRangeStringUntruncated.length, 8) )
        scala.util.Try[java.lang.Double](lowRangeString.toDouble).toOption
    } else null
    val nonRangedValue: Option[java.lang.Double] = scala.util.Try[java.lang.Double](inputValue.get.toDouble).toOption
    val valueOptDouble: Option[java.lang.Double] = Option(rangedValue.getOrElse(nonRangedValue))
    ...
    <do something with valueOptDouble>
}
```

```
Error:(157, 89) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Double]
 required: Double
            val valueOptDouble: Option[java.lang.Double] = Option(rangedValue.getOrElse(nonRangedValue))
```

I'm sure this could be written much more concisely, but what i'm confused about is why the final line results in this error, as it seems both **rangedValue** and **nonRangedValue** are of type Option[Double]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type error is with

```
rangedValue.getOrElse(nonRangedValue)
```

because `getOrElse` here expects `Double` argument but `nonRangedValue` is `Option[Double]`. Perhaps try `orElse` instead of `getOrElse`

```
val valueOptDouble: Option[Double] = rangedValue orElse nonRangedValue
```

Comment: Thanks @mario, changing to orElse means it compiles successfully, eg `val valueOptDouble: Option[java.lang.Double] = rangedValue.orElse(nonRangedValue)`
Why is the `getOrElse` expecting a `Double`, i thought it took the expected type from the first object, `rangedValue` which is also an `Option[Double]`?

Comment: nvm, i think its because the `getOrElse` returns the contained value in this case the `Double`, not the `Option`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to take a look at the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) to learn about useful combinators like `map` and `flatMap`

I really, couldn't understand what your code does, so here is an attempt to solve the same problem.
In any case, I believe the code should be easy to adapt to your real needs, but feel free to ask any questions or provide clarification over the problem so I could edit the code.

```scala
def getValueFromString(inputValue: String): Option[Double] =
  inputValue.split('-').toList match {
    case raw1 :: raw2 :: Nil =>
      for {
        first <- raw1.toDoubleOption
        second <- raw2.toDoubleOption
      } yield if (first < 60.0d) first else second
    
    case _ =>
      None
```

And then you can pass this **method** to a `flatMap` of the original `Option[String]` like this:

```scala
Some("10-30").flatMap(getValueFromString)
// res: Option[Double] = Some(10.0d)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ZxlJlfZUTCS9fPLYA24e9Q/2)*.

Comment: Thanks Luis, i should have said i'm running on scala 2.12 so i get this error when running your code: `toDoubleOption is not a member of String` but i think i understand the approach.  1 question, what purpose does the `Nil` on line 3 serve?  Thanks

Comment: @crispo `str.toDoubleOption` can be replaced with `Try(str.toDouble).toOption` - The purpose of `Nil` is to ensure the **List** had exactly two elements, nothing else, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `inputValue.split("-").head.toDouble`